# PIT not sending interrupts to IRQ0

Tags: c, timer, interrupt, irq

This may be a noobish question,
but I have been following tutorials for writing a small OS.
So far I have setup the interrupt descriptor table, a method for
registering handlers, a default handler (prints int number to screen)
and remapped the PIC's to interrupts 0x20 and up.

I just setup the programmable interval timer to tick at 50Hz but it does
not generate any IRQ0's. I have setup the timer handler at interrupt 32 in
the descriptor table but if I generate the interrupt manually with: `__asm__ volatile ("int $0x20);` I get "Tick: 0x00000001" printed on the screen.

Here is my timer.c file:

```
#include <common.h>
#include <drivers/timer.h>
#include <drivers/isr.h>
#include <drivers/display.h>
#include <drivers/io.h>

u32int tick = 0;

static void timer_callback(registers_t regs) {
  tick++;
  print("Tick: ");
  print_hex_dword(tick);
  print("\n");
}

void init_timer(u32int frequency) {
  register_interrupt_handler(IRQ0, &timer_callback);

  u32int divisor = 1193180 / frequency;

  outb(0x43, 0x36);

  u8int l = (u8int) (divisor & 0xFF);
  u8int h = (u8int) ((divisor >> 8) & 0xFF);

  outb(0x40, l);
  outb(0x40, h);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you haven't programmed the PIC with a mask that enables the PIT interrupt? Usually this is done via reading port 0x21 (Master PIC data port) and then enabling IRQs by writing a new mask to 0x21. Setting a bit in the mask to 0 enables the interrupt. So you'd have to `and` the current bit mask with 0xFE (11111110) to enable the PIT at IRQ0.

Comment: ..or maybe the timer hardware has to be turned on in some power-management register?

Comment: Minimal working PIT example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/9a24f92f36a45abb3f8c37aafc0c3ee9b15563ab/in_pit.S

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou to those who have responded.
Your answers were helpful however, the problem was that
after setting up the IDT and re-mapping the PICs, I
had forgotten to include the assembly to once again
enable interrupts.

PS:
Yes, after re-mapping the PICs I masked them with 0x0
which should enable all interrupts.
  -Thanks Michael Petch.

Also, I am running the kernel in Oracle VirtualBox on
Ubuntu 12.10 with occasional testing on real hardware.
It didn't work on either so I don't think the timer was
in any way disabled.
  -Thanks Martin James